# SVN Commit Fails but TortoiseSVN Commit Works

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am having trouble committing a json file (around 50MB) with the `svn commit` (it complains about the size) and I do not have rights to change server settings.

Error Message:

```
Commit failed (details follow):
Unexpected HTTP status 413 'Request Entity Too Large'
```

The weird thing is, I can commit the same file using TortoiseSVN. Theoretically, then I should also be able to commit with `svn commit`.  Do you have any ideas what is the cause and how to solve this ?

Thanks

Comment: You should specify the version of your command-line client and TortoiseSVN. To find out the version of svn.exe, run `svn --version -v`.

Comment: My svn version is 1.9.7